доброго времени суток ! помогите пожалуйста?
У меня в следующем коде выводится ошибка
viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this,ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(**getApplication()**)).get(DrawingViewModel.class); дело в  том что я переопределяю метод onDraw во вью модели для того чтоб  перерисовывать линию.
как мне стоит изменить код чтоб устранить ошибку.
android studio electric eel
вот весь класс
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

public class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {
    public MutableLiveData<Integer> inputNumber = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public MutableLiveData<Float> X = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public MutableLiveData<Float> Y = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public class DrawingViewModel extends ViewModel {
        private final MutableLiveData<Canvas> canvasLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

        public void setCanvas(Canvas canvas) {
            canvasLiveData.setValue(canvas);
        }

        public LiveData<Canvas> getCanvasLiveData() {
            return canvasLiveData;
        }
    }

    public class DrawingView extends View {
        private final DrawingViewModel viewModel;

        public DrawingView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this,


                    ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(getApplication())).get(DrawingViewModel.class);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            viewModel.getCanvasLiveData().observe(this, new Observer<Canvas>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(Canvas canvas) {
                    // Рисуйте что-нибудь на canvas здесь
                    invalidate(); // Вызывайте invalidate, чтобы перерисовать view
                }
            });
        }
    }






}```


Ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста, с разделом [ask]. Также вам может быть небесполезно разобраться, как здесь устроено форматирование текста, перед тем, как исправить вопрос.
